# gcc inline asm template for constant with out hash

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

I am trying to emit a global SYMBOL based on a #define VALUE. My attempt is as follows:

```
__asm__ (".globl SYMBOL");
__asm__ (".set SYMBOL, %0" :: "i" (VALUE));
```

What is emitted by gcc to the assembler is the following:

```
.globl SYMBOL
.set SYMBOL, #VALUE
```

How can I get rid of the hash in the `.set` before `VALUE`. FWIW, my target is ARM.

Comment: For x86, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers documents a `%c0` modifier that expands to the constant without decoration.  GCC might support the same modifier for ARM.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed it does, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `c` [operand modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Generic-Operand-Modifiers):

```
__asm__ (".set SYMBOL, %c0" : : "i" (VALUE));
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e7K9KGjMz)

gcc used to document this feature as supported only on x86, but it actually worked on ARM as well, and as of gcc 13, it is documented as supported on all targets.

(The other AArch64-specific modifiers, like `%w0` to emit `w11` in place of `x11`, are likewise supported a long way back,  for compatibility with [armclang](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0610/armclang-Inline-Assembler/Inline-assembly-template-modifiers/Template-modifiers-common-to-AArch32-state-and-AArch64-state?lang=en).  They are still not documented by gcc 13, but are [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AArch64-Operand-Modifiers) in the trunk code, so presumably will be a fully documented feature for gcc 14.)

Comment: Perfect. I searched the `gcc` documentation for a list of template modifiers, but could't find the one for ARM.  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

```
#define VALUE 89
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

__asm__ (".globl SYMBOL");
__asm__ (".set SYMBOL, " str(VALUE));
```

The 'VALUE' must conform to something that gas will take as working with `set`.  They could be fixed addresses from some vendor documentation or a listing output that is parsed.  If you want 'VALUE' use `str(s)`, if you want '89' then use `xstr(s)`.  You did not describe the actual use case.